# Set return_state=True to an LSTM layer in loaded model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've trained an encoder-decoder model and saved it to a file, but it turns out I forgot to set the return_state flag on decoder's LSTM layer to true. Now I'm unable to implement inference. Is it possible to set the return_state flag for LSTM outside the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not verified the below code by training the model again, but this might help you:

1. First, load the existing Keras model using `tf.keras.models.load_model` method:

   ```
   model = tf.keras.models.load_model('models/model.h5')
   ```
2. If the `LSTM` layer lies at the 2nd index, we get the `Layer` object:

   ```
   lstm = model.layers[2]
   ```
3. The `lstm` is an `tf.keras.layers.LSTM()` object. We can modify the `return_state` parameter:

   ```
   lstm.return_state = True # Set the updated value here
   ```

**Tip:**

Like `return_state` in `LSTM`, I observed that we can also modify the arguments of all types of layers in Keras. Here, I also tried changing the units argument of a `Dense` layer:

```
dense.units = 23 # Previous value was 64!
```